# Disable foreign key constraints without disabling other errors?

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions

I'm using this code to truncate and insert new values into a table. Some other tables have foreign keys that reference this one, so I need to disable checking foreign key constraints before truncating it.

My problem is that my code not only disable foreign key constraints but also ignores other kidns of errors. For example trying to insert a string into a date field prints "OK" and commits the transaction.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1='ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL'
DELETE FROM Users_Login
BULK INSERT Users_Login FROM '\\STRMV3302\Temp\lisandro.h.vaccaro - Users_Login.txt'  WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = '||', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n', FIRSTROW = 2, CODEPAGE = 'ACP')
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1='ALTER TABLE ? ENABLE TRIGGER ALL'
IF @@ERROR = 0
BEGIN
COMMIT
PRINT 'OK'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
ROLLBACK
PRINT 'ERROR'
END
```

When I try to insert a table with a '#' on a DateTime field I get this output, and lose everything on the table:

```
(2 row(s) affected)
Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 3, column 4 (LogoutDate).
OK
```

Is there a way to ignore foreign key constraints while still catching other errors?

Comment: This is a bad idea and a clear sign of a poor design. You NEVER under any circumstances delete the PK records and leave the FK records. And doing that with user logins is just downright irresponsible. Insert your data to a staging table, then update/delete/ insert only the appropriate records to the table that has the PK  (although with logins, I would inactivate rather than delete, you still need the associated past records) .

Comment: If you have data integrity problems with the file you are inserting, you need to insert to a staging table where the fields are varchar(max) or nvarchar(max) and then clean up the bad data before going to a production table. It is risky to your data integrity to ever insert data in a bulk insert directly into  a production table. Only bad things happen when you do that.

Comment: `and lose everything on the table` you got the solution to that in the previous question but you accepted a bad answer.

Comment: The code worked perfectly without the two EXECs that disable the key constraints, so it's not really a problem with the way it's rolling back the transaction. However for some reason diasabling the key constraints is also ignores inserting a string value into a datetime column.

Answer (score 0):

This does not look like a foreign key constraint error, it looks like a `BULK INSERT` error where you are trying to load a value into a column but SQL cannot reconcile your value with the column's datatype. Specifically, if I'm reading your information right, it would appear you are trying to load the value `#` into a datetime column.

Beyond that, I agree with @HLGEM--though, lacking intel on your application and processes, I'm reserving judgment on *why* you are doing what you are doing. Even so, why are you disabling the foreign keys? Do you plan on re-enabling them later? If a lot of tables reference this one, that could be incredibly hard and messy to do. The usual Tactic (as @HLGEM says) is to load the data into a "staging" table, then copy/merge/otherwise move it into the "live" table with thorough and rigid data integrity checks and controls.